# Kinetic theory: Computing the flux density

Tags: integration, kinetic-theory, gas

The problem is the following:

Set up:

A sealed box contains a collisionless classical gas of particles, each of mass $m$. The box is
coupled to a thermostat such that interactions between particles and the box walls maintain
the temperature of the gas but which can otherwise be neglected.

The single particle distribution function is given by
$$f(\vec{r} , \vec{p} ,t) = \frac{\rho}{(2 \pi m k_B T)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \exp \left(-\frac{p^2}{2mk_B T} \right)$$

The question:

The box is divided into two compartments by an internal wall in the $yz$-plane which has a small hole. Using $f$ as given above, calculate the flux $j_x$ of particles incident on the hole moving in the positive $x$ direction, as a function of $T, \rho $

What I'm struggling is how to use the fact that there is a small hole. Do I just compute $j_x$ as usual? In that case, I find it to be just 
$\int \frac{p_x}{m} f(\vec{r},\vec{p},t) d\vec{p}$

When I switch to polar coordinates, using $p_x = p \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi)$ I get the integral of $\cos (\theta)$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ which vanishes, giving me that $j_x =0$, which I am not sure if it is correct since it doesn't use the fact that there is a wall there and a small hole.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Physical reasoning**

You clearly get zero because you are integrating on all the values of $p_x$, from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, which means you are summing the two fluxes of all the particles going from the left to the right and vice versa, but since the gases in the two sub-boxes are at equilibrium, the fluxes are equal and opposite in sign.

**Suggestion**

If you want to study only the flux of particles going from the left box to the right box, you simply need to take positive values of $p_x$. In polar coordinates the angle $\phi$ goes from $-\pi/2$ to $+\pi/2$ (not from $0$ to $2\pi$).

**Solution**

However the integral is much simpler in cartesian coordinates:
$$
j_x = \rho \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\pi}}
\int_0^{\infty} dp_x p_x e^{-\alpha p_x^2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dp_y e^{-\alpha p_y^2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dp_y e^{-\alpha p_z^2},
$$
where I set $\alpha = (2mk_BT)^{-1/2}$.
This is much simpler because you have two one dimensional gaussian integrals that give you a factor $\pi/\alpha$, and the trivial integral
$$
\int_0^{\infty} dp_x p_x e^{-\alpha p_x^2} = \frac{1}{2\alpha}.
$$
All together your final result is
$$
j_x = \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{4 \pi \alpha^2}} = \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{8\pi m k_BT}}
$$